# Excluding a rectangular region from an image in FITS

Tags: ds9

I am a complete beginner in astronomy. While learning DS9, I came up with the following question.

Say I want to exclude a boxed region from an image FITS. The corresponding parameters according to [Chandra](http://cxc.harvard.edu/ciao/ahelp/dmregions.html) is

- Box = (xcenter,ycenter,width,height)
- Box = (xcenter,ycenter,width,height,angle)

Although the name is self-explanatory yet I am confused about their respective units. What unit is used to label these parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually pixel coordinates.
What I would do is to let DS9 make a region file, as your documentation site says it supports them.

To do so:

- Open file in ds9
- From region->shape select the kind of region you want.
- Click on edit->region
- Draw the shapes you want (just click on the img)
- Click region->save. In the coordinates box choose physical pixel coordinates.

Probably that should work... Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Several different units are possible. If you double click on the box a dialogue window will open where you can adjust the size/location. In the drop-down menus on the right hand site, you can choose which unit and coordinate system you want.

[image]